# I was invited to join the Jehovah's Witnesses, I'm interested but I have only hear bad things about them

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

***Summarize the problem:***

In my own words. My aunt invited me to a reunion so I can look at how it is to be a Jehovah's Witnesses and then "maybe" join them.
The problem is, I'm starting searching of what I can expect and I only find bad experiences.
Is anything good if I ended up joining them? I see a lot of "limitations".
I'm running out of options, and to be honest, Faith is the last thing I have, even born as a Catholic.

***Provide details:***

I'm having the worst year of my life.
I had a lot of relationship problems, friendships who seems to go well, then dating then rejected multiple times when trying to formalize the relationship causing that I end up alone without friends.
Recently that caused on me a strong depression (10 years long) that could only be "minimized" (but not cured) by getting on a "Institute of Mental Health".
I recently go out and my mind is starting to deteriorate again. She knows about that and she invited me to join them.

Comment: there are bad experiences/history with any denomination. IMO if they help you get closer to Jesus go for it. There are great people all over, in every denomination

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Your question is likely to be closed because it does not fit with the aims and objectives of this site.  We do not give pastoral advice.  Please take our tour to understand what sort of questions are acceptable: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If you're Catholic the defacto prescription is a good private confession.  Look up times in your area, lots of parishes will have Confession an hour before masses - especially on Saturdays

Comment: For this, and other Stack Exchange sites, questions must be specific and objective.  So, questions that relate directly to you are inappropriate.  Similarly so is vaguely saying that you have heard "bad things".  Asking about a specific "bad thing", without saying it is bad, and ideally with a reference to where you read it, would solicit objective answers confirming or refuting the claim.  E.g. "Why aren't JWs allowed to attend non-religious events that are held in Catholic church buildings?".

Answer (score 2):

Jehovah's Witnesses do not have "reunions" and they don't simply invite people "to join them".  What they do is get people to study with them over a long period of time till they are familiar with and accept all their beliefs.  They expect interested people to join them in speaking to other people with a view to getting them to study with them. They are also expected to attend all the weekly meetings.

If someone wants to be baptised and become a member, they have to answer a load of questions about what the Witnesses believe, how they are expected to conduct themselves by living up to the highest moral standards, and why they must give their unquestioning obedience and loyalty to the Governing Body.

Your aunt may have genuine concern for you but your mental health issues need to be addressed by professionals.

Comment: I'm sorry if I use the wrong term. I mean kind of when they reunite and sing. At least she told me thats what they do on those gatherings and I was welcome to see how is it. I'm going with a professional for my mental health, but still I'm alone without friends (which doesn't help also to my mental health) which she told that i can find a lot of friends and brotherhood there. I know is not that Im part of them with going to a single gathering, but I'm worried about what to expect.

Comment: @Syntax_Error It sounds as if your aunt is inviting you to our "meetings" or what others may refer to as "services". You can view the video "[What Happens at a Kingdom Hall?](https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/meetings/video-kingdom-hall/)" and of course, I encourage you to visit the [jw.org](https://www.jw.org/) website for more information.